# How to save and restore my sklearn model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pickle, machine-learning-model

I am using `pickle` to store my machine learning model like this:

```
import pickle
with open('mymodel','wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(gbc,f)
```

Now, in another computer i wanted to test this model. So i am restoring my model and passing data like this:

```
with open('mymodel', 'rb') as fin:
       clf = pickle.load(fin)

X_new_preds = clf.predict(dataset)
```

But i am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model 
n_features is 20 and input n_features is 19
```

I can understand from the above that, while training i have done lot of pre-processing , like in data i was having categorical feature, then i removed multicollinear columns and all. So in my final `DataFrame` i was having 20 feature (remember, this come after lots of pre-processing).

So, i wanted to know, how can i store these information using `pickle`. Or how can i restore my model and can use in new data.

Edited:

I did tried this also

```
#Using Joblib
from sklearn.externals import joblib
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
joblib.dump(gbc, filename)
loaded_model = joblib.load(filename)
X_new_preds = clf.predict(dataset)
```

But getting same value Error.

Comment: Doesn't *whatever you use as the model* have built-in methods to do this?

Comment: I have to give this model to client, so i want solution,once model is save , he can use it simply.  I can not do all the pre-processing step there, because still i will conflict with number of columns

Comment: Which library are you using? Perhaps pickle isn't the right tool for the job.

Comment: I have done all the things in sklearn only and used GradientBoostingClassifier algorithm for training

Comment: Ok, can you suggest me then, like how can i save my model and data structure so that i can use it in future

Comment: If `pickle` doesn't throw you an error at the moment you save or load, you shouldn't have any problem. However, the error is clearly indicated `n_features is 20 and input n_features is 19`. You're passing 19 features instead of 20.

Comment: In machine learning , we do lot of pre-processing things, after that only we pass data for training. but while predicting we dont know what was the process used.

Comment: Then you need to store that process somewhere and apply that during prediction. You can save the preprocessing sklearn classes same way as you saved the model. Show the complete code which does the pre-processing.

Comment: It is very long code. i am applying missing value, collinierity, dummies for categorical variable.

Comment: Well then, as I said above, you need to store that process somewhere. Because if you dont, then the results which you get on the new data will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your model persistence and loading. The problem is that you're doing some preprocessing on the data, which you're not saving.

You have two options:

1. Have a documentation stating what the model accepts, and the user/client would know what to give to the model.
2. There's some preprocessing done by you, which you can combine with your model together using a `Pipeline`.

Here's an example of a pipeline, taken from the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html):

```
>>> from sklearn import svm
>>> from sklearn.datasets import samples_generator
>>> from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
>>> from sklearn.feature_selection import f_regression
>>> from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
>>> # generate some data to play with
>>> X, y = samples_generator.make_classification(
...     n_informative=5, n_redundant=0, random_state=42)
>>> # ANOVA SVM-C
>>> anova_filter = SelectKBest(f_regression, k=5)
>>> clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
>>> anova_svm = Pipeline([('anova', anova_filter), ('svc', clf)])
>>> # You can set the parameters using the names issued
>>> # For instance, fit using a k of 10 in the SelectKBest
>>> # and a parameter 'C' of the svm
>>> anova_svm.set_params(anova__k=10, svc__C=.1).fit(X, y)
...                      
Pipeline(memory=None,
         steps=[('anova', SelectKBest(...)),
                ('svc', SVC(...))])
>>> prediction = anova_svm.predict(X)
>>> anova_svm.score(X, y)                        
0.829...
>>> # getting the selected features chosen by anova_filter
>>> anova_svm.named_steps['anova'].get_support()
... 
array([False, False,  True,  True, False, False, True,  True, False,
       True,  False,  True,  True, False, True,  False, True, True,
       False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> # Another way to get selected features chosen by anova_filter
>>> anova_svm.named_steps.anova.get_support()
... 
array([False, False,  True,  True, False, False, True,  True, False,
       True,  False,  True,  True, False, True,  False, True, True,
       False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Once you persist your whole pipeline, you can ask the client to give the model (pipeline) the data in the original form. You can also develop some custom transformations and add them to the pipeline as long as you follow the required API.

Comment: I did thought of this also, Now suppose that, while in training. one of my column was having categorical variable with 5 class. so it will generate 4 dummies columns for that class. But while predicting on client side, he passed only one row of course which will have one class only in that row. In this way even if i used pipline, it will not able to create that extra 4 dummies columns for me.

Comment: It would if your first _transformation_ in the pipeline is to transform a categorical input with a one-hot encoder.

Comment: I did tried, but it not helped me. i did search for one-hot encoder inside pipeline. but did not get luck.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong there. You can ask another question specifically for why your transformation's not working.